# How can I ask Mac OS to allocate memory at a specific address?

Tags: macos, memory

On Linux, you can allocate memory at a specific address like so:

```
void *foo = (void *)0xDEADBEEF;
size_t MyLength = 1024;
void *bar = mmap(foo, MyLength, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_FIXED, MAP_PRIVATE, -1, 0);
```

Is this same method also possible on Mac OS, or if not, how does one do this on Mac OS?

My goal is to write a kernel extension to map out (and thus disable) a region of defective memory on a MacBook Pro with a non-removable defective RAM chip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is std `C`. It compiles fine on *Xcode*. Make sure to add:

`#include <sys/mman.h>`

Before you invest too much time writing a kernel extension for macOS be aware of its [deprecation](https://developer.apple.com/support/kernel-extensions/).

Comment: Do you know of another way to trigger this as early as possible in the boot process, other than a kernel extension?